# Parsing 8-byte hex integers in R

Tags: r, hex

Context: I'm trying to write a parser in R for the track files exported by my preferred GPS app.  The files use a custom binary specification, with latitude, longitude, and timestamps all represented as 8-byte, big-endian, signed integers. For example, latitude is degrees north x10^7.  This is the first time I've messed around with parsing raw/hex representations.

Let's say I have 3 raw integers:

```
# Should parse as 377441228
lat = as.raw(c(0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x16, 0x7f, 0x4b, 0xcc))
# Should parse as -1195899101
lon = as.raw(c(0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xb8, 0xb8, 0x07, 0x23))
# Should parse as 1618678057000
time = as.raw(c(0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x78, 0xe0, 0xbb, 0x08, 0x28))
```

The first approach I found was to use `readBin()`. This works correctly for `lat` and `lon` but not `time`:

```
# 377441228: correct
readBin(lat, integer(), size = 8, 
        signed = TRUE, endian = 'big')
# -1195899101: correct
readBin(lon, integer(), size = 8, 
        signed = TRUE, endian = 'big')
# -524613592: incorrect
readBin(time, integer(), size = 8, 
        signed = TRUE, endian = 'big')
```

The next approach was to do some string wrangling and pass through `as.numeric()`. This worked for `lat` and `time`, but not `lon`:

```
library(magrittr)
parser = function(hex) {
    hex |> 
        paste(collapse = '') %>%
        paste0('0x', .) |> 
        as.numeric()
}
# 377441228: correct
parser(lat)
# 1.844674e+19: incorrect
parser(lon)
# 1.618678e+12: correct
parser(time)
```

How do I parse these?

Comment: What was expected for `time`? Do remember how date-times are represented. (I don't get that result; I get -524613592 which is "1953-05-17 19:00:08 PDT" when given to `as.POSIXct` with the standard origin value). Close vote for needing clarity. (I'm getting frustrated with questions that are incomplete or not reproducible.)

Comment: Per the comment in the first block, `time` should parse as 1618678057000.  It's milliseconds rather than seconds; I don't know why, that's just per the file spec.  `as.POSIXct(1618678057, origin = '1970-01-01')` gives 2021-04-17 09:47:37 PDT, which is when I started recording the track I'm using to develop this parser.

Comment: The time value is too large to be represented as an integer in base R.  You can read it in as a double and convert it to a 64bit integer.  `library(bit64); \`class<-\`(readBin(time, double(), size = 8, endian = "big"), "integer64")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this little function which uses only base R. It converts the raw data into bits, orders these into a single big-endian vector of 1s and 0s, then uses their [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation to convert them to the appropriate value.

```r
parser <- function(x) {
  bits <- sapply(x, function(y) rev(as.integer(rawToBits(y))))
  sum(bits[-1] * 2^(62:0)) - bits[1] * 2^63
}
```

Testing, we have:

```r
lat  <- as.raw(c(0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x16, 0x7f, 0x4b, 0xcc))
lon  <- as.raw(c(0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xb8, 0xb8, 0x07, 0x23))
time <- as.raw(c(0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x78, 0xe0, 0xbb, 0x08, 0x28))

parser(lat)
#> [1] 377441228
parser(lon)
#> [1] -1195898880
parser(time)
#> [1] 1.618678e+12
```

If you prefer a vectorized version that will handle multiple values at once, you can do:

```r
parser <- function(x) {
  sapply(x, function(z) {
    bits <- sapply(z, function(y) rev(as.integer(rawToBits(y))))
    sum(bits[-1] * 2^(62:0)) - bits[1] * 2^63
  })
}

parser(list(lat, lon, time))
#> [1]     377441228   -1195898880 1618678057000
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>